# Spark: how to not use aws credentials explicitly in Spark application

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

In my Spark application, I have aws credentials passed in via Command Line arguments.

```
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", awsAccessKeyId)
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", awsSecretAccessKey)
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
```

However, in Cluster Mode explicitly passing credential between nodes is huge security issue since these credentials are being passed as text.

How do I make my application to work with IAmRole or other proper approach that doesn't need this two lines of code in Spark app:

```
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", awsAccessKeyId)
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", awsSecretAccessKey)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add following config in core-site.xml of hadoop conf and cannot add it in your code base

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
  <property>
  <name>fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId</name>
  <value>my_aws_access_key_id_here</value>
  </property>
  <property>
  <name>fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey</name>
  <value>my_aws_secret_access_key_here</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

To use the above file simply `export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=~/Private/.aws/hadoop_conf` before running spark or `conf/spark-env.sh`

And for IAM Role there is already bug is open in spark 1.6 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16363